# Run s/w on closing of Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: java, c++, c, windows

I want to run an application on closing/Disconnecting Remote Desktop Connection. Is there's any way to keep record of Remote desktop session start-stop timing in winndows xp/win 7.

Comment: I am still searching where to start.

Comment: [Remote Desktop Services reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383494(v=vs.85).aspx) provided by WINAPI _should_ help you.

Comment: An easy way: monitor Windows Events for log-in/log-off. As alternative set-up an alert on the Performance Monitor snap-in, it'll run the app for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a Windows service and listen for SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE.  One of the parameters for that event is the session state, which in this case you would be interested in either WTS_SESSION_LOGON/WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF or WTS_REMOTE_CONNECT/WTS_REMOTE_DISCONNECT depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

On start of remote desktop connection you can try this.
Here is a psuedo-code of what you have to do:

1. Java application (Listener), registered as a Windows Service and runs on system stratup.
2. Listener application keep listening until some .exe file is opened. (Here in this case It will be **mstsc.exe**)
3. Listener execute code (or call another application)

Comment: mstsc is the RDP client; I assume he's talking about server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can run any program using [Task scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> - When the computer enters an idle state.
> - When the system is booted.
> - When a user logs on.
> - When a Terminal Server session changes state.

You can even [add tasks from command line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_logon)